# Is there any way to clear specific number of lines in a terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

Here's the use case:

1. A `node.js` script clears the console.
2. Then it sends some metadata to the console. (**Module Name**, and **tagline**. Sort of like an App's header.)
3. It sends past data to the console. (Sort of like an App's initial content, which, since it's past, will not change after issuing. At least, not until exiting.)
4. It does what it's supposed to, what the module was made for, and it pipes that to the console as well.

Step 4 is a continuous process. And hence you can think of Step 4 as if it were a ***clock***. After every second, the clock resets and displays the new time.

`\033c` would have worked fine if Step 1-3 weren't there. But, they are, and the only way I can think of is to print all the data again.

It works, but it is not the most performant code. So, is there any way I can clear Step 4's output, and then reprint it with the changes?

***Note:*** The last line of the terminal is not necessarily the last line of the program.

Comment: All terminals understand control codes that allow you to position the cursor, erase lines etc. The terminfo database contains these, and the terminal type is given by the `TERM` environment variable. Libraries to make use of this are e.g. `curses`. But this is old technology, no idea how to access it from node.js ...

Comment: Thanks for the response, @dirkt. That's what I thought too, that it must be possible. But, unfortunately, I need a `node.js` wrapper around it or some sort of a bash command that I can exec in `node`.

Answer (score 2):

> **\033c would have worked fine if Step 1-3 weren't there.**

`\033` is the ASCII `Escape` control-code character. I believe `Escape c` is the ANSI terminal command sequence to reset the terminal.

You can probably issue a `CR` (carriage return) to move the cursor to the left margin followed by `Escape [ K` (clear to end of line).

If the output of step 4 is multiple lines, you need to issue the appropriate commands for move cursor to row, column and clear to end of screen.

A search for "ANSI terminal control codes" should find useful reference material.

> **I need ... some sort of a bash command**

`man tput`

consider

```
$ echo aaa bbb ccc `tput cr`xxx
xxx bbb ccc

$ echo aaa bbb ccc `tput cr`xxx `tput el`
xxx
```

or

```
$ echo aaa bbb ccc; echo ddd eee fff
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff

$ echo aaa bbb ccc; echo ddd eee fff; echo `tput cup 23 3` ZZZ
aaa bbb ccc
ddd ZZZ fff
```

or

```
$ echo aaa bbb ccc; echo ddd eee fff; echo `tput cup 22 3` ZZZ `tput ed`
aaa ZZZ
```

where the capability codes used are

- `cr` = carriage return (cursor to left margin).
- `el` = clear from cursor to end of line.
- `cup` = cursor-positioning.
- `ed` = clear from cursor to end of screen.

These capability codes are listed in `man terminfo`.

If you want to know what tput is doing you can do something like

```
$ (tput cup 23 3; echo) | cat -v
^[[24;4H
```

Where `^[` represents the control-code `Escape` (\033).

This will give you values you can use in whatever way you were intending to use your `\033c`